# DotNet Core Console Application notarization procedure?

Tags: .net-core, command-line, macos-catalina, codesign

I'm looking for a detailed procedure for signing and notarizing a DotNet Core Console Application for macOS Catalina (10.15).  My app builds and runs quite happily, but the signature process is not working for me.  That said, I don't know if I've messed something up in the project definition or the build process or if I've munged the parameters to codesign.

When looking at project options in Visual Studio for Mac for a DotNet Core (3.1) Console Application, there aren't any settings particular to Mac Signing as there are for explicitly macOS DotNet/Xamarin applications.

No amount of Google searching has located a procedure that walks through step-by-step how to set up the project and get it signed and notarized.  In general, the best I can get is a "main executable failed strict validation" message during codesign.  My latest and greatest (and possibly way off the mark) codesign command is the following:

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: James Ramsey (XXXXXXXXXX)" --timestamp --options runtime -f --entitlements FMComparison_DotNet/entitlements.plist --deep <pathToMyPublished app>/FMComparison_DotNet
```

Does anyone know what the optimal procedure is for accomplishing this goal?

Thank you.

Comment: Console applications are distributed differently (via homebrew or other ways), so notarization is probably not necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, this command line app is a resource of an electron app.  If I can't sign the dot net app, I can't sign the electron app... at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Several resources (like [this](https://www.digicert.com/kb/code-signing/mac-os-codesign-tool.htm)) seem to indicate that you only need to sign the .app as a whole, so not sure whether you have to sign that console application.

Comment: I have exactly same issue, and I have followed all the code signing and notarization procedure and still get errors running the final executable.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: For those who still looking at it now, there is a sample repo you can find here https://github.com/martincostello/dotnet-macos-notarization-example